# Trying to center my menu

Tags: css, centering

I can't seem to understand how I should center this menu among the logo and the login/register

http://jsfiddle.net/hnnsr97x/2/

HTML

```
<header id="header">
    <div id="LogReg">
        <h2><a href="#" id="loginform">Login</a> | <a href="#">Register</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
        <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img alt="Logo" title="logo" src="Logo/logo.png" ></a>
    </div>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul class="main_menu">
            <li><a href="#">MENU1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> 
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    width:100%;
}

#logo, #menu {
    float:left;
}

#menu {

}

#menu li  {
display:inline-block;
}

#LogReg {
    text-align:right;
}
```

The fiddle is quite empty because I cleared it from some things I tried

So I'm here to ask for someone to explain how I should get the menu in the center? I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Logo, menu and login text all in same line?

Comment: The login and register is a line higher, but logo and menu are on the same line

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/hnnsr97x/6/

the `calc(50% - 500px)` is saying make the `margin-left` 50% minus the `width` of the `image` and half of the `menu`

```
#logo{
  float:left;
}
#menu {
  float:left;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 500px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean centering the menu like this?

```
<header id="header">
  <div id="LogReg">
          <h2><a href="#" id="loginform">Login</a> | <a href="#">Register</a></h2>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="logo">
      <a class="logo" href="index.html">
        <img alt="Logo" title="logo" src="Logo/logo.png" >
      </a>          
    </div>

    <nav id="menu">
      <ul class="main_menu">
        <li><a href="#">MENU1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MENU2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MENU3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS style:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
}

#menu {
  float: right;
}

.main_menu {
  margin: 0;
}

#menu li  {
    display: inline;

}

#LogReg {
    text-align: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanzuniga/66xnov5z/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/AkashPinnaka/0eq1f9az/embedded/result/ 
I am assuming you are intended to make them align in a line. And obviously you know the height of your logo. Let me assume your logo is of height 40px.
Modify your HTML code to the following code.

```
<header id="header">    
   <div id="logo">
      <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img alt="Logo" title="logo" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/9-credit-1.jpg"></a>       
      <a href="#">MENU1</a>
      <a href="#">MENU2</a>
      <a href="#">MENU3</a>                 
   </div> 

  <div id="LogReg">
      <a href="#" id="loginform">Login</a> | <a href="#">Register</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

And CSS code as following

```
#header {
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
}
div#logo{
  float: left;
}
div#logo a{
 /*  line-height: 100px; */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div#LogReg{
  line-height: 40px;
  float: right;
}
img{
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px; /* just assumed to be 80px wide. Width doesn't matter as long as it is not too long. */
}
```

I took img height as 40px in css as I assumed.
This aligns logo, navigation menu and login|register in the same line.

If you need Login|Register a bit higher than logo and menu, just reduce the line-height of **div#LogoReg** to less than **40px**.

And if u want some margin on both left and right sides, wrap your whole header content in another **div** tag as shown below

```
<header id = "header">
  <div id = "header_in">
  </div>
</header>
```

and give the width of div#header_in as 80% or something you like. This gives the margin on both left and right sides of your header.

```
div#header_in{
  width: 80%;
}
```

**Let me know if you want anything different.**

Answer (score 0):

See working demo here [Centered Menu](http://jsfiddle.net/musa7290/hnnsr97x/10/)

HTML:

```
<header id="header">

  <div id="LogReg">
    <a href="#" id="loginform">Login</a> | <a href="#">Register</a>
  </div>
  <div id="logo">
    <a class="logo" href="index.html">LOGO</a>
  </div>


    <nav id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">MENU1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MENU2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MENU3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav> 

</header>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    width:100%;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}

#LogReg {
    float:right;

}

#logo{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left:10px;
}

#menu{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#menu li  {
    display:inline;
}
```